$\vec L$, $\vec S$ and $\vec J$ of the atom or electron when considering the Zeeman effect
I am confused regarding the different angular momenta considered when dealing with the Zeeman effect.
I don't know whether the different angular momenta are attributed to the entire atom, exposed to an external magnetic field or to an electron. And this is confusing me.
Let's consider the normal Zeeman effect.
In this case the interaction is between the magn. field and the orbital angular momentum $\vec L$.
For an arbitrary energy level n and for l=1, the energy state with quantum nr. n,l=1 is split into 3 new lines. Obviously here we are considering an electron and the interaction of it's orbital angular momenta with the magnetic field.
If l=2, then the level will be split into 5 sub-energy levels.
This example, to my understanding, clearly shows that the interaction considered is between the individual orbital angular momenta of the electrons with the magn. field. It cannot be the total orbital angular momentum of the entire atom, which is a vectoral sum of the individual orbital angular momenta of all the electrons.
But in some instances, the opposite is hinted at:
1 - In the Wikipedia article about the Zeeman effect, it is mentioning the LS coupling and it is said that we are considering the total $\vec L$ and $\vec S$ of the atom. Assuming that this is the case, how can one, in either Zeeman effect (normal or anomalous), describe the splittings that occur for an arbitrary energy level (nlm_l or jm_jls) when one only has one value for the total $\vec L$ and $\vec S$? While the $\vec L$ of different electrons are different? I don't understand how one can calculate/evaluate what splittings happen at an arbitrary energy level when considering the total corresponding angular momentum instead the one that characterizes the electrons in that level?
2 - The normal Zeeman effect itself is an indicator that the interaction considered is between the total orbital angular momentum of the atom $\vec L = \sum_i \vec L_i$, the total Spin of the atom $\vec S = \sum_i \vec S_i$ or the total angular momentum of it $$\vec J = \vec L + \vec S$$ in LS coupling or $\vec J=\sum_i \vec J_i$ in jj coupling.
In the normal Zeeman effect $\vec S=0$ and this is a singlet state. But a singlet state considers two electrons and their total spin angular momentum. Therefore the $\vec L$ should similarly be the total orbital angular momentum of the atom.
And again, I cannot comprehend how can we predict how the splittings of different instances (energy levels) occur when instead of considering the "local" angular momenta that characterize an electron at an instance (n,l,m_l,s,m_s) we consider the global/total angular momenta.
Am I overthinking this, or is there something more to it?

The angular momenta in question are the total ones for the whole atom. You already do this to some extent, but your question will be more answerable if you explain in more depth why you think that that "cannot be".

@EmilioPisanty  I will give an example.
Let's consider an atom in which the normal Zeeman effect is manifested. This implies a total Spin of the atom with the spin quantum number s=0.
Now consider this scenario:
This atom is characterized by a total orbital angular momentum $\vec L$ to which a corresponding quantum number $L$  belongs. Consider two electrons, one which has l=1 and one which has l=2. The energy levels will be split into 3 and 5 sub levels. Now, if you only have the value of the total orbital ang. momenta, how can you predict this splittings?

One talks about the fact that for l=1 the level splits in 3 sub levels, because here you are considering the orbital quantum number of the individual orbital angular momentum of the electron. The same for l=2. You are considering the interaction between the $\vec L$ of the electron that has l=2 with the B field. If you were to consider the total orbital angular momentum and it's quantum number, you'd only have 1 value. How would you be able to describe the splittings that would take place for 2 electrons, one of which has l=1 (n is whatever) and one l=2 ?

@EmilioPisanty Essentially my question can be summed up as:
How can you predict the splittings of different energy levels (characterized by different values of the quantum number nlm_l) when you consider the angular momentum of the entire atom, which is the same in value for every case ?

I have to say: I am not surprised you’re confused because I can’t figure out what you’re trying to say.  Can you please clarify how many electrons you are considering? In the wiki page figure, for instance, they are talking about one $s$ electron with $\ell=0$ but you still see splitting due to the coupling between $\vec S$ and $\vec I$, so the possible values of $F$ are $1$ and $2$.

@ZeroTheHero Let's consider the following scenario: You have a multi-electron atom present in an external magnetic field. For simplicity the total Spin of the atom is zero.
Now for the total orbital angular momentum $\vec L$ you find some value L different than zero (i.e 2,3...).
Someone asks you:
For the case when I consider one electron with an arbitrary value of n and l=1. How many sub-levels you get?
For a 2nd electron that I consider with some arbitrary value n and l=2. How many sub-levels you get? One the same atom with the same total orbital angular momentum value

@ZeroTheHero Whatever claims you make about the level of splitting I want you to utilize the value you get for the total orbital angular momentum, that of the atom, which irrespective of  the energy level you consider, the value of the quantum number of the total orbital angular momentum is the same

You have been asking this for quite a long time in the chat. I know you are already consulting textbooks, which should already have dispelled your confusion. It should be a thing you should have been able to figure out by yourself, even though, yes, this is a complicated topic of rather immense difficulty. It will be openly discussed if you had consulted a textbook that cares much about atomic spectroscopy.
Let's start by answering your earlier chat question about normal v.s. anomalous Zeeman. I am actually surprised that Wikipedia is doing a good job there, but as is usual, it still misses the context. Zeeman effect was found so early on, 1896, that it not only was before Stern-Gerlach experiment showing spin-half for the first time (1922; Uhlenbeck and Goudsmit introduced electron spin in 1925), it was before quantum theory entirely (1900, Planck's distribution). As such, when Bohr's model rolled around in 1913, the only kind of angular momentum that they knew about, was orbital angular momentum, and that was at least explain-able by Old Quantum Theory.
You can read Pauli's Nobel lecture on the tortured discoveries involved. To be fair, it is confusing even after knowing the facts, so the pioneers definitely suffered to get where we are.

$m_\ell$ and $m_s$ are never good quantum numbers. Although this fact can only be arrived at if you use the Dirac equation, having fine structure corrections, especially spin-orbit coupling; considering this fact helps guide the understanding of all these magnetic effects. For hydrogenic atoms, thus, you must realise that it is not $\ell$ and $s$ that is coupling with the magnetic field, but rather $\left|n,\ell,s,j,m_j\right>$ the ``fixed" $j$ and various $m_j$ that is coupling with the magnetic field. It is strictly technically wrong to consider individual $m_\ell$ and $m_s$ interacting with the magnetic field.
This suggests that only $jj$ coupling is correct. As you can see from the popularity of $LS$ coupling in elementary quantum theory presentations, this is wrong. The reason is incredibly subtle. The spin-orbit coupling term in Hydrogenic solution to Dirac-Coulomb problem goes as $\dfrac{Z^4}{n^3\ell^3}$ and is initially quite small. This means that for top few rows of the periodic table, you should start with ignoring spin-orbit interaction, and then introduce it back via perturbation. For the bottom few rows, you have to consider $jj$ coupling first, and then introduce the magnetic field as a perturbation.
Mind you, this means that in the $LS$ coupling case, you are essentially considering $\ell_1\ell_2$ coupling, for all the valence electrons, and $s_1s_2$ coupling, because these are coming from the exchange-Coulomb interaction, which is huge. Then, you will get a "fixed" $L$ value, a "fixed" $S$ value, and then you can do your $LS$ coupling.
In reality, the real effect is extremely complicated and you have to treat the whole subspace, i.e. many different $LS$ subspaces if using $LS$ coupling, and many different $jj$ subspaces if using $jj$ coupling. The whole point is that you have to include enough of the almost-degenerate energy subspace until you have something that you can capture the correct physics. Then you diagonalise the Hamiltonian over this subspace. The diagonalisation will always be some $J,m_J$ subspace, and only this one is the thing that agrees with experiment.
Needless to say, the nuclear angular momenta will also intrude, when you are measuring to incredibly high precision. Then you will have even more of a headache.
